# Lining up logo with menu pills in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap

Tried to get this going quite a bit, but so far no luck, but my css skills are still in the beginning stages.

I'm using bootstrap, and trying to have a simple logo at the top of my page with nav pills on the same horizontal line, but aligned to the bottom of the logo.

I've tried all the solutions that I could find about aligning content to the bottom of a div, but so far no luck.

What I currently have is in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UaujG/9/.  Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix is to add:

```
.span6 {
margin-top: 24px;
}
```

Comment: well, it'd be adding another class since span6 is one of the building blocks of twitter bootstrap, but thats possible.  Seems a little inflexible/inelegant solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly with a bit of jQuery

```
function sizing() {
    var logoheight=$('#logo').height();
    var navpadding=32;
    $('#nav_buttons').css('padding-top', (logoheight-navpadding)+'px');
    if(logoheight<navpadding){
    $('#logo').css('padding-top', (navpadding-logoheight)+'px');    
    }
}
$(document).ready(sizing);
$(window).resize(sizing);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/UaujG/25/